# Can sharepoint search crawl items in a hidden list?

Tags: sharepoint

I have had mixed results with this.  If i have an item in a hidden list, search does not seem to crawl it.  But If i make it visible, and crawl it will get indexed.  and if I hide it again and update it it will get crawled again!

Does anyone know if search is supposed to be able to search items in a hidden list or not?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hiding a list only removes it from lists, without affecting access to the list itself. If the list is new, the search crawler will not see it when it looks for lists. If it has been crawled before however, the url is already in the search index and can be updated without needing to see it in the lists collection.